# Convertir un Array Binario a Decimal con recursividad en JAVA

Tags: java, array, recursión, binario

Estoy intentando realizar un metodo el cual reciba un arreglo como parametro y que mediante un metodo recursivo, se pueda devolver ese mismo numero pero en notacion decimal.

Basicamente primero estoy instanciando este arreglo:

`int[] binario = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};`

Y este es el metodo que estoy utilizando

```
public static int convertirBinarioADecimal(int[] bin, int i, int decimal) {

        if (i < bin.length) {
            if (bin[i] == 1) {
                decimal += Math.pow(2, ((bin.length - 1) - i));
            }
            return convertirBinarioADecimal(bin, i++, decimal);
        } else {
            return decimal;
        }

    }
```

Y estaba llamando al metodo de esta manera:

````
res = convertirBinarioADecimal(binario, 0, decimal);
System.out.println("res = " + res);```
````

Mis disculpas por lo basico de la pregunta pero habia dejado mis estudios de programacion por un par de años pero ahora volvi y me esta costando un poco mas

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda